# Display MySQL BLOB'd image on webpage without separate script (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, blob

So I've got some images stored in a MySQL database as BLOB's (I know it's better to just store the directory and do it that way, but this is what I need to do for now) and I need to display them on a webpage. Now, I know how to make a script and give it an image header and pull the img src from there, but I have a lot of images from different places for different uses, so I'd have to make a ton of these scripts and I'd rather not clutter up my files like that.
Anyway, does anyone know of a function or something I can use to display the image that will run on the same page?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've done in `php` to call an image stored a `blob` in `mysql`

```
img width=120 height=120 src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($row['Image']).'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`data:` URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to hold the image.

Comment: Pardon my noobishness, but I've never heard of this technique. I'm reading up on it now, but could someone explain how I would go about using it? Thanks

Comment: Wherever you would have `http://...` in a `img src`, you instead put `data:` followed by the mimetype, the encoding, and the encoded image data.

Comment: Ah, very interesting. Thanks, I'm gonna try this.